# ¿Qué es lo que hace mysqli_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql

Ya se que se utiliza para evitar la inyección SQL en lugares como los formularios por ejemplo.

¿Pero como logra eso?¿Como valida si el texto ingresado es de SQL o no?

Busque en varios lugares pero todos dicen lo mismo, que sirve que evitar la inyección, pero no lo explican realmente. Y la documentación de PHP no la entiendo mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo que hace es *"escapar"* los caracteres especiales. Es decir, que les coloca por delante un símbolo de escape () para evitar que determinados caracteres se usen como son. Habitualmente son caracteres como ' " \n \r.
De esta manera evita que esos caracteres reservados (es decir, parte de comandos MySQL) se cuelen en un valor usado dentro de una sentencia MySQL.
Te pongo un ejemplo muy simple

```
$nivel = "'1' or '1' = '1'";
$query = "SELECT nombre, nivel FROM clases where nivel = $nivel";
$res = $gestorBase->query($query);
```

Tu pretendes un listado de registros de la tabla donde nivel sea 1, ese nivel lo sacas de un input en un formulario, por ejemplo. El usuario en el formulario añade lo de **or nivel !=''** ahora lista todos los registros de la tabla.
Pero si haces

```
$nivel = "'1' or '1' = '1'";
$nivel = $gestorBase->real_escape_string($nivel);
$query = "SELECT nombre, nivel FROM clases where nivel = $nivel";
$res = $gestorBase->query($query);
```

Ahora  se obtiene es un error de sintáxis al ejecutar el query. La información extra introducida no es ejecutable, porque las ' están escapadas.
Es un ejemplo muy simple, pero creo que te puede dar una idea de como funciona este mecanismo de protección.
¿Es la respuesta que buscas?

Comment: Osea, básicamente inutiliza los caracteres especiales que se usan para MySQL?

Comment: Si, evita que puedas meter comandos dentro de los select, update, insert...